# Incorrect formula result via VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have made a simple program to put a particular formula in Excel. The problem is the occurrence of single inverted quotes in the result.

Where the result should be `='[Fiber Loss Report - 7210 DCN.xlsx]1310'!G9`,
the result i get is `='[Fiber Loss Report - 7210 DCN.xlsx]1310'!'G9'`

```
Sub CopyValues()
Dim n As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim rng As Range
y = 6
For n = 9 To 175
    rngText = "D" & y
    Range(rngText).Select
    'rng.Select
    'Range("D6").Select
    formulaText = "='[Fiber Loss Report - 7210 DCN.xlsx]1310'!G" & n
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = formulaText
    rngText = "E" & y
    Range(rngText).Select
    formulaText = "='[Fiber Loss Report - 7210 DCN.xlsx]1310'!G" & n + 1
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = formulaText
    n = n + 2
    y = y + 1
Next
End Sub
```

Please let me know on how can I avoid the occurrence of these single quotes.

Comment: `Range(rngText).Formula = formulaText`

Comment: In addition to the use of `.Formula` instead of `.FormulaR1C1` it seems that you should be using `For n = 9 To 175 Step 2` or `For n = 9 To 175 Step 3` and get rid of the `n = n + 2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `.value` instead of `.FormulaR1C1` solves the problem. :)

Answer (score 3):

Further to my comments below your question...

You need to find trends in your code. That ways you can avoid the loops.

For example, your formula from `D6` to `D61` increase from `G9` to `G12` to `G15` and so on. Similarly for Col E.

So there is a trend. The next question you can ask yourself is "*What formula can I write where I can get results like 9, 12, 15, 18 and so on?*". The formula is

```
=(ROW()-3)*3
```

If you put that formula say in `G6` and pull it down, you will get that sequence.

Now also instead of looping we can write formula to the entire range is one go. So we simply combine the above with `Indirect`. See this

**Shortest possible code?**

```
Sub CopyValues()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim fName As String

    fName = "Fiber Loss Report - 7210 DCN.xlsx"
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        '"='[Fiber Loss Report - 7210 DCN.xlsx]1310'!G9"
        .Range("D6:D61").Formula = "=INDIRECT(" & Chr(34) & "'[" & _
                                   fName & "]1310'!G" & Chr(34) & _
                                   " & (ROW()-3)*3)"

        .Range("E6:E61").Formula = "=INDIRECT(" & Chr(34) & "'[" & _
                                   fName & "]1310'!G" & Chr(34) & _
                                   " & (ROW()-3)*3+1)"
    End With
End Sub
```

**JUST FOR FUN**

I can convert the above code in just two lines. Simply replace `Sheet1` with the relevant sheet name.

```
Sub CopyValues()
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D6:D61").Formula = "=INDIRECT(" & Chr(34) & "'[Fiber Loss Report - 7210 DCN.xlsx]1310'!G" & Chr(34) & " & (ROW()-3)*3)"
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E6:E61").Formula = "=INDIRECT(" & Chr(34) & "'[Fiber Loss Report - 7210 DCN.xlsx]1310'!G" & Chr(34) & " & (ROW()-3)*3+1)"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyValues()

    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    j = 6
    For i = 9 To 175 Step 3
        Range("D" & j).Formula = "='[Fiber Loss Report - 7210 DCN.xlsx]1310'!G" & i
        Range("E" & j).Formula = "='[Fiber Loss Report - 7210 DCN.xlsx]1310'!G" & i + 1
        j = j + 1
    Next

End Sub
```

---

Result: ='[Fiber Loss Report - 7210 DCN.xlsx]1310'!G9

Answer (score 1):

You can just remove single inverted quotes and change to RC format:

```
Sub CopyValues()
 Dim n As Integer
 Dim y As Integer
 Dim rng As Range
 y = 6
 For n = 9 To 175
    rngText = "D" & y
    Range(rngText).Select
    'rng.Select
    'Range("D6").Select
    formulaText = "=[Fiber Loss Report - 7210 DCN.xlsx]1310!R" & n & "C7"        
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = formulaText
    rngText = "E" & y
    Range(rngText).Select
    formulaText = "=[Fiber Loss Report - 7210 DCN.xlsx]1310!R" & n + 1 & "C7"        
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = formulaText

    n = n + 2
    y = y + 1
Next
End Sub
```